# Permanent Marker Brushes for Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I'm looking for a way to simulate a permanent marker in Photoshop. All I have been able to find are pre-drawn brush strokes of circles, strokes etc. ([Permanent Brush](http://mvrh.deviantart.com/art/Permanent-Marker-Brush-Pack-103964311)), but not a permanent marker brush tip which would allow me to draw/write whatever I want.

Can anyone recommend PS brushes for this purpose? I don't mind paying for them, so it doesn't have to be a free Brush set.

Comment: Semi off-topic: I've never been a big fan of Corel Painter, but it has huge amount of brushes that imitate traditional tools. I'm sure that it has some types of marker brushes. Can't remember if it had permanent markers though. Just in case you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

The typical look of permanent markers comes from the change in pressure, fading, streaks and bleed (from turns and slower streaks). This is hard to recreate in an authentic way and often simply done on paper and then scanned. Pages full of different strokes and attempts are not uncommon and actually not that time-consuming.

My guess is you want to have a reliable reproducable style? Maybe starting a brush library on your own will solve that better than any photoshop brush can.

The only "automated" way I can think of is actually making one in Illustrator as a path style with defined ends. But that gets repetitive too.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use something like [this](http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/25-high-resolution-marker-pen-brushes/) as your brush and then lower the flow of the brush down to around 50% and paint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like already said above, the real thing is always the best. But if that's not an option you could use some commercial brushes, they really give a nice and realistic effect.

Some that I love are these 2 packs:
- Kyle Webster Art Markers (https://creativemarket.com/kyletwebster/257826-Kyles-Art-Markers-for-Photoshop)
- Real Markers by HEJ! (https://creativemarket.com/Eilert/339653-REAL-MARKERS-FOR-PHOTOSHOP)

[image: Example of second suggestion]